# Whats the latest command line tools for Mac0S 10.15.7 Catalina

Tags: git, macos, operating-system

My git is not working on VS code and i get the following message :

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

i believe i need to install the latest command line tools, what is the latest one i need to install?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode package should be what is needed to get the latest core development tools on Mac Os X. You will most likely want to get version 11.5 or later.